# Redirecting Multiple Commands as Input

Tags: io-redirection, input

What is the correct way to redirect the output of multiple commands as input for another command?

e.g.

```
$ command < (command2 | grep pattern)
```

Comment: Do you really mean the output of multiple commands ot the output of **one** pipeline? And which shell are we talking about, or are you looking for the perfectly portable solution?

Comment: @HaukeLaging No; the output of one pipeline as the input to one command.

Comment: How is this different from extending the pipeline? `command2 | grep pattern | command`

Comment: @HaukeLaging Ah, I didn't know they were the same! Thank you. Would you like to answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: The `<( .... )` syntax is primarily used in those cases where a simple pipeline _does not_ work, either because some program refuses to read from standard input and requires a file argument, or because there are _several_ commands whose output should be fed into one other command, i.e., `cmd <(cmd1) <(cmd2)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(This refers to bash in case of doubt)

The output of one command or one pipeline can be made the input of another command by creating a (or extending the existing) pipeline:

```
command1 | command2
command1 | command2 | command3
```

Several commands (including pipelines) can be combined with a subshell or a list (group command). This combination becomes the first part of the pipeline then:

```
(command1; command2 | command3; command4) | command5
{command1; command2 | command3; command4;} | command5 # note the ; before }
```

Another possibility is a "here string" (or even a "here document"):

```
command2 <<< $(command1)

command2 <<EOT
First input line
$(command1)
Last input line
EOT
```

**Other cases**

**Command substitution** is used when the output shall be part of a command line i.e. if one command shall see the output of another as its own parameter:

```
echo $(date)
```

echo sees the output of `date` as its parameter; as if it had been typed in the command line.

**Process substitution** makes the output of another process appearing as the content of a (non-seekable) file given as parameter on the command line.

```
grep bar <(echo $'foo\nbar\nbaz')
```

looks to grep like

```
echo $'foo\nbar\nbaz' > /path/to/file
grep bar /path/to/file
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to execute the commands using the [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) syntax.

```
$ command < $(command2 | grep pattern)
```

Comment: Tried it? http://pastebin.com/686v9iQr

Comment: @manatwork Would you mind making your findings a formal answer so that this question can be successfully closed?

Comment: @HaukeLaging, I prefer to let the answer's owner to make the necessary corrections, instead of posting a concurrent answer. After all, Spack seems to be new here and this answer's age is less than half hour.